# Linear model with equality constraints across two factor variables

Tags: r, constraints, lm, categorical-data

This question is related to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/linear-model-with-constraints, but a slightly different scenario.

I have a simple 2-factor linear model with continuous outcome `Y`. `factor1` has ~350 categorical values, and `factor2` has the same ~350 categories. I want to constrain the coefficient on each level to sum to zero *across* the two factors.

(The reason for this is that each level of `factor1` and `factor2` enters either positively or negatively in any training example, but never appears twice in the same example.)

Here is an example dataset illustrating the situation, where there are four levels of each factor:

```
            Y factor1 factor2
1  -1.2470416       A       B
2   4.3368592       C       D
3   1.0005147       D       A
4  -2.8309146       A       C
5   1.7501315       B       D
6  -0.8372193       B       A
7   3.3542627       C       A
8   4.3319422       D       C
9   1.4937895       D       B
10  2.0951559       A       D
11 -2.6610207       C       D
12 -4.9917367       D       B
13  2.2424169       D       A
14  1.0205409       C       A
15 -3.4584576       C       B
```

The statistical model I want to estimate is:
$$ y_{(i,j)} = \alpha_i-\beta_j+\varepsilon_{(i,j)} $$
where $(i,j)$ is an outcome that depends on the pair. `factor1` marks $i$ and `factor2` marks $j$. If group `A` shows up in `factor2`, the parameter on `A` should be equal to the negative of if it showed up in `factor1`. Thus, I would like to set $\alpha$ equal to $\beta$ for all $i$ and $j$.

I can estimate a (nonsensical) version of this model in `lm()` fairly easily as follows:

```
Y <- c( -1.2470416, 4.3368592 , 1.0005147 , -2.8309146 , 1.7501315 , -0.8372193 , 3.3542627 , 4.3319422 , 1.4937895 , 2.0951559 , -2.6610    207 , -4.9917367 , 2.2424169 , 1.0205409 , -3.4584576 )
factor1 <- c( "A" , "C" , "D" , "A" , "B" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "D" , "A" , "C" , "D" , "D" , "C" , "C")
factor2 <- c( "B", "D", "A", "C", "D", "A", "A", "C", "B", "D", "D", "B", "A", "A", "B")
DF <- data.frame(Y,factor1,factor2)

lm(Y~factor1+factor2,data=DF)
```

and I get the following output:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   0.5363     2.5856   0.207    0.841
factor1B     -0.4579     3.1121  -0.147    0.887
factor1C      0.4047     2.4925   0.162    0.875
factor1D      1.8737     2.4098   0.778    0.459
factor2B     -3.6252     2.2050  -1.644    0.139
factor2C     -0.7226     2.8903  -0.250    0.809
factor2D      0.7561     2.2094   0.342    0.741
```

Note that, theoretically, `factor1C` should equal `-factor2C` as dictated by my model. This is not the case in the simple `lm()` output because I didn't impose any constraints.

So what I would like to do is to estimate

```
Y ~ factor1 + factor2  [subject to factor1+factor2=0 for each level of factor1, factor2]
```

In plain English, this would be something like

```
model2 <- lm(Y~factor1-factor2, data=DF)
```

But this of course is not how R interprets that expression (because putting a minus sign in a `model` statement tells R to exclude that variable from the model).

I've read up on contrasts, but I don't think there is a way to do this. I've also read up on `glmc`, but didn't see a straightforward way of incorporating it for factors that have this many levels. Also, it's not clear to me that generating a new `factor3 = factor1-factor2` is a well-defined operation for this specific scenario. Finally, I tried running `model3 <- lm(Y+factor2 ~ factor1, data=DF)` but received an error.

My sense is that I would need to create a constraint matrix by looping through the levels of each variable. I'm sufficiently new to R that I'm not sure exactly how this is done. Any help would be appreciated.

Note that it is quite easy to do this in Stata, as follows:

```
input ID  y factor1 factor2
1  -1.2470416       1       2
2   4.3368592       3       4
3   1.0005147       4       1
4  -2.8309146       1       3
5   1.7501315       2       4
6  -0.8372193       2       1
7   3.3542627       3       1
8   4.3319422       4       3
9   1.4937895       4       2
10  2.0951559       1       4
11 -2.6610207       3       4
12 -4.9917367       4       2
13  2.2424169       4       1
14  1.0205409       3       1
15 -3.4584576       3       2
end


constraint   1 2.factor1 = -2.factor2
constraint   2 3.factor1 = -3.factor2
constraint   3 4.factor1 = -4.factor2
cnsreg y i.factor1 i.factor2, constraints(1/3)
```

which gives the following output:

```
Constrained linear regression                   Number of obs     =         15
                                                F(   3,     11)   =       0.73
                                                Prob > F          =     0.5554
                                                Root MSE          =     2.9875

 ( 1)  2.factor1 + 2.factor2 = 0
 ( 2)  3.factor1 + 3.factor2 = 0
 ( 3)  4.factor1 + 4.factor2 = 0
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     factor1 |
          B  |   2.104393   1.439085     1.46   0.172    -1.063011    5.271798
          C  |   .5222649   1.377463     0.38   0.712    -2.509511     3.55404
          D  |   .6589209   1.266188     0.52   0.613    -2.127941    3.445783
             |
     factor2 |
          B  |  -2.104393   1.439085    -1.46   0.172    -5.271798    1.063011
          C  |  -.5222649   1.377463    -0.38   0.712     -3.55404    2.509511
          D  |  -.6589209   1.266188    -0.52   0.613    -3.445783    2.127941
             |
       _cons |   .5054862    .829675     0.61   0.555    -1.320616    2.331589
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How does one do the above in R?

Comment: I'm not clear whether you want to constrain the _coefficients_ on `factor1` and `factor2` to sum to zero, or whether the _values_ are constrained to sum to 0...

Comment: My understanding of this question is that `factor1` and `factor2` are perfectly multicollinear. So you can only include one or the other...

Comment: I don't think this is really a question about R / R code, & as such I don't think this question is off topic in that respect. OTOH, I don't really follow your situation, or how it motivates your suspected solution. For that matter, I not certain I'm clear on what your suggested solution *is* (eg, I share @MichaelChirico's confusions). It might help to develop a simpler example w/ just a few levels & an example dataset to go w/ it, & then add some additional explanation.

Comment: Alternatively, try writing out the math you think is behind the model. Either would elucidate your troubles

Comment: @MichaelChirico Please see my edits. Hopefully these have clarified what I am trying to do. Also, notice that this is easily estimated in Stata. What I am looking for is an R equivalent.

Comment: @gung Hopefully the example has cleared things up.

Comment: If your question is, "How does one do the above in R?", it would be clearer, but also clearly off topic here.

Comment: @gung, Yes, that is my question. If off-topic, do you know where it would be on-topic?

Comment: Possibly on [SO]. You could flag your Q & ask the moderators if they would be willing to migrate it. Otherwise, you would need to try the r-help listserv.

Comment: Thanks! Just flagged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the most popular (but not accepted) answer in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/linear-model-with-constraints, this problem is easily solved by creating a new variable which is the difference in the "one-hot" encoded factors.

In Stata, one can do this as follows:

```
* one-hot encode each of the factors
qui tab factor1, gen(f1dum)
qui tab factor2, gen(f2dum)

* generate difference in one-hot vectors
forv x=1/4{
    gen fdiffdum`x' = f1dum`x'-f2dum`x'
}

* regress y on differenced one-hot vectors
reg y fdiffdum2 fdiffdum3 fdiffdum4
```

Which gives the following output:

```
      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        15
-------------+----------------------------------   F(3, 11)        =      0.73
       Model |  19.5429062         3  6.51430205   Prob > F        =    0.5554
    Residual |  98.1766922        11  8.92515383   R-squared       =    0.1660
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =   -0.0614
       Total |  117.719598        14  8.40854274   Root MSE        =    2.9875

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   fdiffdum2 |   2.104393   1.439085     1.46   0.172    -1.063011    5.271798
   fdiffdum3 |   .5222648   1.377463     0.38   0.712    -2.509511     3.55404
   fdiffdum4 |   .6589209   1.266188     0.52   0.613    -2.127941    3.445783
       _cons |   .5054862    .829675     0.61   0.555    -1.320616    2.331589
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In R, one can do this as follows:

```
factor1mat <- model.matrix(~factor1, DF)
factor2mat <- model.matrix(~factor2, DF)

factordiffmat <- factor1mat - factor2mat

summary(lm(Y~factordiffmat, data=DF))

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                0.5055     0.8297   0.609    0.555
factordiffmat(Intercept)       NA         NA      NA       NA
factordiffmatfactor1B      2.1044     1.4391   1.462    0.172
factordiffmatfactor1C      0.5223     1.3775   0.379    0.712
factordiffmatfactor1D      0.6589     1.2662   0.520    0.613
```